# How to handle single data points in ChartJS?

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am using the ChartJS library via react-chartjs-2.
For my charts, I am using the **Time Cartesian Axis** alongside the **date-fns** adapter.

I am having an issue when rendering only a single data point on my line chart / bar chart / scatter chart. It currently renders like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vlCk.png).

It seems that since there is only one data point (and no other points to reference), it displaying the timestamps in the x scale like:

- 12:46:26.999 p.m.
- 12:46:27.000 p.m.
- 12:46:27.001 p.m.

And also nothing is drawn on my line chart when there is only a single point, since I am using a point radius of 0 and they are only shown on hover.

How can I handle these single data point cases so that

- Only the actual timestamp of the data point is rendered (not the extra ones on either side)
- I can format that timestamp nicely
- Something is displayed on the line chart when there is just a single point

I was thinking I would have to override chart options like line chart point radius, `source` field in `ticks` option, etc. to configure the options for the special case of a single data point maybe?

Or are there better, cleaner ways to handle this?